# How do I stop the mini-buffer prompting for stuff if I've moved on

Tags: emacs

From time to time Emacs gets into a state where it is constantly asking me questions on the mini-buffer. This is usually asking for a directory path for an error from compile-mode. However whenever I respond to the prompt it just prompts again for another file.

Killing the compilation-mode window doesn't stop the flow of annoying mini-buffer prompts. Is there any way to kill all outstanding mini-buffer prompts? I thought 3 C-g's would do it but apparently not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x abort-recursive-edit</kbd>.

Comment: Normally bound to `Ctrl`+`]`. Another command that gets you out of recursive edits is `ESC ESC ESC` (`keyboard-escape-quit`).